# Defining an isomorphic map

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

[image]

Wondering about the isomorphism defined at the bottom to show $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. The map given is $g(x + \mathbb{Z}) = 2\pi x + 2\pi \mathbb{Z}$ but would it also be correct to define a simpler map, as $g(x) = 2\pi x$. That seems like it would also work and be slightly cleaner to show than the current isomorphism or would that be incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing down the same map, just by abuse of notation. In particular, the map you are using is taking is sending $x \mapsto 2 \pi x$, and then, in coset representation it is the map the authors use.